# Benchmark datasets for testing multiple regression or multivariate regression model?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, dataset

I have a question as a newbie. I'm working on a tool using regression analysis( linear, multiple, multivariate) to derive a regression model. To verify the correctness of the tool, I'm trying to find a benchmark, or a benchmark dataset to test the tool. Any idea or comments are all welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to look at [Opendata.SE](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

See NIST's [Statistical Reference Datasets](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/). These include data chosen or designed to present numerical challenges to regression algorithms. The Longley data, with highly collinear predictors, is perhaps the most famous example.

Comment: That's a good start thanks! Any ideas where to get a dataset with more observations?

Answer (score 4):

Generate some random data yourself in whatever language you're using, that follow the assumptions of your model, e.g., for linear regression generate $X$, then $\beta$, then do $y = X\beta + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is normally distributed with mean zero and sd of say 1. See if you can recover the correct $\beta$ when varying the error stdev. Compare with the multitude of established tools for doing regression.

Comment: (+1) Certainly useful first steps, but you'd want some *hard* test cases if possible.

Comment: Simulation is always good but if you want to publish an algorithm you want to have comparable results to others.